# Adding custom relative layout to one single liner layout

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout

I have made following relative layout in an xml file lets say add_relative_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:id="@+id/addAccountLinearLayout">



</LinearLayout>
```

Above is the main layout in which i want to add copies of below Code file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/UIContainer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/amountLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="Amount"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/amount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" >

    </EditText>
```

I have another android xml file named as Show_all.xml. It is a linear layout xml

I want to add this relative layout above as many times as i want in this show_all layout

currently i am using this code

```
private void callOnCreate()
      {
          linear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.addAccountLinearLayout); // the layout in which i want to make dynamic copies of this layout.
          layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.layout.ui_relative_layout_style); // name of xml File of above code.

          for (int i=0; i < 4; i++)
          {
              Account account = accountArray.get(i);
              linear.addView(layout, i);
          }   
      }
```

I am getting Null point exception. Please tell me what to do .

Best Regards

Comment: where you getting null pointer exception. please post the logcat so it help us to answer you..

Comment: @umar put your full logcat and NullPointerexception give you line no. of your Activity check which line gives Null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello Umar I have no idea how you can use xml layout to add Dynamically But you can use Below Code to get Your Required thing add in to LinearLayout

```
public RelativeLayout createViewTOAdd(){
    lp=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout=new RelativeLayout(this);
    mRelativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    TextView mTextView=new TextView(this);
     RelativeLayout.LayoutParams Textview_lp=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    mTextView.setText("Amout");
    Textview_lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
    Textview_lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    Textview_lp.leftMargin=10;
    mTextView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    mTextView.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.TextStyle);
    //mTextView.setLayoutParams(Textview_lp);
    EditText mEditText=new EditText(this);
     RelativeLayout.LayoutParams EditText_param=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
     EditText_param.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
     EditText_param.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
     EditText_param.rightMargin=10;
    //mEditText.setLayoutParams(EditText_param);
    //mRelativeLayout.addView(mTextView, 0);
    //mRelativeLayout.addView(mEditText, 1);
    //mRelativeLayout.addView(mTextView);
    //mRelativeLayout.addView(mEditText);
    mRelativeLayout.addView(mTextView, Textview_lp);
    mRelativeLayout.addView(mEditText, EditText_param);
    return mRelativeLayout;
}
```

Now How to add View in to LinearLayout is Below

```
    mLinearLayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLinearView);

    mLinearLayout.removeAllViews();

   for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        mLinearLayout.addView(createViewTOAdd(), i);
    }
```

Comment: Do you know how to set background of relativelayout using drawable/abc.xml ?

Comment: well i added list view and made a custom adapter. But thanks anyway for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Hey your are using findViewById to get the instance of relativelayout which is not available in your current layout show_all.xml .thats why you are getting null pointer exception.So create separate layout for that specific relativelayout and names that xml layout file as UIContianer then try to use below code

```
private void callOnCreate()
      {
          linear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.addAccountLinearLayout); // the layout in which i want to make dynamic copies of this layout.

 LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
 View vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ui_relative_layout_style, null);
          for (int i=0; i < 4; i++)
          {
              Account account = accountArray.get(i);
              linear.addView(vi, i);
          }   
      }
```

Comment: please tell now which line you r getting error and also post xml code of both layout files

Comment: Error is at  linear.addView(layout, i);

Comment: activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE -- activity is not being recognized. What should i do? i don't need to do this only one time. It is like i have list of accounts and i need to make copies of this layout and show account info in each layout and all these layouts are inflated in my main account.

Comment: sorry remove activity simply use LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE